# Using TLS for a CNAME redirect

Tags: redirect, ssl, dns, cname

*(Sorry, not sure if this would be better suited for Superuser or Serverfault).*

I'm using Zoho email for a website I run. It allows custom domain mapping by pointing a CNAME record from `mail` to `business.zoho.com`. My domain uses TLS/HSTS, so when I go to `mail.example.com` I get a certificate error because the cert is for `*.zoho.com` and not `mail.example.com`. Is it possible to use a cert on my site with the CNAME record so that the cert check passes? This doesn't make sense to me because it's actually accessing the zoho.com server, but I don't know a lot about this.

*(Side question: Is it referred to as SSL, TLS, or just HTTPS now?)*

Answer (score 6):

The certificate has to match the hostname in the URL. Thus if the URL is `mail.example.com` the certificate must match this name. If the certificate is for `business.zoho.com` it will not match. CNAME etc do not change the name in the URL.

It is not possible to include `business.zoho.com` into your own certificate since you don't own this domain, i.e. no certificate agency will issue such a certificate.

> (Side question: Is it referred to as SSL, TLS, or just HTTPS now?)

SSL is the older name for TLS, TLS 1.0 is in effect SSL 3.1. Often it is written as SSL/TLS. HTTPS is the HTTP protocol inside a SSL/TLS layer.

Comment: That makes sense. I know this isn't possible, but a cert would need to include both `mail.example.com` AND `business.zoho.com` to be valid with a CNAME redirect then? Chrome only complains that it isn't valid for `mail.example.com`. For the second question, I apologize that I wasn't clear. I meant to ask which way I'm actually supposed to refer to it. Most places still say SSL, but since that's not used anymore (or at least shouldn't be) is it "proper" to refer to it as TLS?

Comment: @Vaindil: proper are both SSL and TLS but they are ambiguous because they might also refer to SSL 2.0/3.0 vs TLS 1.x. So best use SSL/TLS if you mean the protocol in general and HTTPS if you mean HTTP inside SSL/TLS.  And it is for a certificate to contain both domains and this would solve the problem. But a CA will only issue such certificate if you can proof that you own both domains.

Comment: There will be no redirect in the browser. The browser will still show up the original url. But the content will be fetched from the ip returned by the resolver. So if the certificate that  the browser receives from that ip does not contain a CN/SAN refernce for the url in the address bar then it will show up Not Secure.